# iOS retrieving javascript variables from UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, variables

I have an html file that has a <`div`> and that I am loading into a UIWebView and I need to know how many lines of text are in the div, so I can check that with javascript:

```
<script>
function countLines() {
    var divHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;
    var lineHeight = parseInt(document.getElementById('myDiv').style.lineHeight);
    var lines = divHeight / lineHeight;
    alert("Lines: " + lines);
}
</script>
```

and it does alert the variable "lines"

In Objective-C how can I retrieve this variable from my UIWebView and then use it in my code?

Thankyou!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The UIWebView method `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` is the sole interface to the JavaScript environment. It evaluates and returns a string representation of the value of a JavaScript expression you pass to it. So, for example:

```
// simplified expression, no function needed
NSString *expr = @"document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight / document.getElementById('myDiv').style.lineHeight";
// now pass it to the web view and parse the result
int lines = [[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:expr] intValue];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is easy:

```
NSString *jsString = @"function countLines() {var divHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;var lineHeight = parseInt(document.getElementById('myDiv').style.lineHeight);var lines = divHeight / lineHeight;return lines;};countLines();";

NSString *responseString = [MywebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

And you should have the value in the responseString variable, which you can convert from a NSString to number :-)

Comment: The <script> tags will cause this to fail, and there's no need to define a function just to call it. It could be an IIFE or a simple expression.

Comment: You might need to call the function at a custom JavaScript event and that's why I kept it...

Comment: @JohnCromartie You are correct about the script tags. Editing to remove them