# How to send and receiving data from Xcode (objective c) to php

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurlrequest

I am trying to send a username and password from xcode to a php file that I have made. As I am new to both xcode and php and for the purposes of the simple application I am making, the username and password is a predefined "123456". I am having a lot of trouble sending the username and password to the php site, and receiving a response. When my code communicates and establishes a connection, it does not read the variable echoed in the php file. Instead it obtains the entire source code of the page. My code is below:

Objective C code:

// I have set an alert view, and set two buttons (continue = buttonIndex==0 and cancel = buttonIndex==1)

```
    // The user continues from the alert view

    if(buttonIndex==0)
{
    NSString* username = @"123456";
    NSString* pass = @"123456";

    // I combine the two strings to send to the php page, and insert a : between the two strings

    NSString* combined = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, pass];
    NSString *post = combined;

    // Now I attempt to post the data to the php page
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.sulaimanmajeed.com/login.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
    {
        webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

}

Now, I also have the other methods which need to be called when doing a post:

```
    -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [webData setLength: 0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSString *loginStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    // NSLog(loginStatus);
    dataOutput.text = loginStatus;
    [loginStatus release];

    [connection release];
    [webData release];
}
```

My php code is really simple:

```
<?php

$usernameEntered = $_GET['user']; $passwordEntered = $_GET['pass']; $full = 'Choose';

$username = array(
    "123456",   "234567",   "345678",   "456789" );

$password = array(
    "123456",   "234567",   "345678",   "456789" );

$accounts = array(
    "Chequings-874576",
    "Savings-793756",
    "Visa-018375",
    "Mastercard-375836" );

$b = 0; $elementsInArray = count($accounts);

$isTrue = "FALSE";

if (($usernameEntered== $username[0]) && ($passwordEntered == $password[0])) {
    $isTrue = "TRUE"; } elseif ((usernameEntered == $username[1]) && ($passwordEntered == $password[1])) {
    $isTrue = "TRUE"; } elseif ((usernameEntered == $username[2]) && ($passwordEntered == $password[2])) {
    $isTrue = "TRUE"; } elseif ((usernameEntered == $username[3]) && ($passwordEntered == $password[3])) {
    $isTrue = "TRUE"; } else {
    $isTrue = "FALSE"; }

if( $isTrue == "TRUE" ) {   for ($i=0; $i < $elementsInArray; $i++)   {       $b = $i;    $full  = $full . ':' . $accounts[$b] ;   }
     echo $full;

}

if( $isTrue == "FALSE" ) {
          echo "error:error 2:test 1:test 2:test 3";


}

?>
```

So, dataOutput.text should return a "true" value, because the username and password I provided was a default "123456". However dataOutput.text only returns the entire source code of the website. Could someone assist me in finding out why it does not output true, and where my code went wrong? I have been working on this for 2 days, and I am stumped. Thank you in advance.

P.S.

The output I receive in dataOutput is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><!-- HTML generated by Network Solutions Website Builder --><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Sulaiman Majeed login</title><meta name="robots" content="index, follow" /><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" /><meta name="description" content="Welcome to my website"><meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"/><meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache"/><meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1"/><script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/user.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/simplegallery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/photo_album.js"></script><link type="text/css" href="/scripts/PrebuiltBlockStructure.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet"><link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/scripts/template.css" id="wb-template.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/scripts/layout3.css" id="wb-layout3.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/scripts/website.css" id="wb-website.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="/scripts/print.css" id="wb-print.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/scripts/12custom.css" id="wb-custom.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/scripts/icwebsiteelement.css" id="wb-icwebsiteelement.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/share/scripts/PrebuiltBlockStructure.css" id="wb-/share/scripts/PrebuiltBlockStructure.css" /></head><body onload="initClientMenu();sizeColumns();"><!-- Start content section --><div id="wb-container-outer"> <div id="wb-container-inner"> <div id="wb-layout"> <div id="wb-layout-inner"> <div id="wb-layout-top-header"> <div id="wb-navigation-subtop-header">                                              </div> <div id="wb-top-subbasenav"></div> </div> <div id="wb-header-nav"> <div id="wb-navigation-top-header"> <div id="wb-navigation-bottom-header">                                                    </div> </div> </div> <div id="wb-layout-header"> <div id="wb-layout-header-mask" class="wb_region">           <table id="wb_con__42340" class="wb_con" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> <tr> <td id="wb_col__45678" class="wb_col" width="50%" valign="top" style="">                             </td><td id="wb_col__5673453" class="wb_col" width="50%" valign="top" style=""></td> </tr> </table>        </div> </div> <div id="wb-layout-header-base"></div> <div id="wb-layout-top-2"> <div id="wb-navigation-subtop">                         <div><a href="home.html" class="tertiary" target="_self"><h3>Home</h3></a></div> <div><a href="resume.html" class="tertiary" target="_self"><h3>Resume</h3></a></div>                      </div> <div id="wb-top-subbasenav"></div> </div> <div id="wb-container-contentwrapper"> <div id="wb-layout-sidebar"> <div id="wb-navigation"> <div id="wb-navigation-top"> <div id="wb-navigation-bottom">                                     <div><a href="home.html" class="tertiary" target="_self"><h3>Home</h3></a></div> <div><a href="resume.html" class="tertiary" target="_self"><h3>Resume</h3></a></div>                                  </div> </div> </div> <div id="wb-basenav"></div> <div id="wb-navbasewrap" class="wb_region"> <div class="wb_dropzone_y"> </div>           <table id="dz-tablewb_element_text__02773140" class="dz-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"> <tr> <td align="left"> <div id="wb_element_text__02773140" class="ic-element"> <div></div> </div> </td> </tr> </table>        </div> </div> <div id="wb-layout-main"> <div id="wb-layout-main-inner-1"> <div id="wb-layout-main-inner-2" class="wb_region wb-text-content">           <table id="wb_cl__12342346" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="" width="100%"> <tr> <td>              <table id="wb_con__056756794678680" class="wb_con" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> <tr> <td id="wb_col__089563564560" class="wb_col" width="100%" valign="top" style="">                               </td> </tr> </table>                       <table id="wb_con__1231213564678" class="wb_con" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> <tr> <td id="wb_col__335786456" class="wb_col" width="70%" valign="top" style="">                                    <table id="dz-tablewb_element_php__1358289049875_15" class="dz-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"> <tr> <td align="left"> <div id="wb_element_php__1358289049875_15" class="ic-element"><php?  ;  ?></div> </td> </tr> </table> </td><td id="wb_col__234456134" class="wb_col" width="30%" valign="top" style="">                                   </td> </tr> </table>              <table id="wb_con__5675679467868" class="wb_con" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> <tr> <td id="wb_col__8956356456" class="wb_col" width="100%" valign="top" style="">                                </td> </tr> </table>           </td> </tr> </table>        </div> </div> </div> <div style="clear: both"></div> </div> <div id="wb-layout-footer"> <div id="wb-layout-footer-inner-1" class="wb_region"> <div class="wb_dropzone_y"> </div>                  </div> </div> </div> </div> </div> </div><table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="other_footer"> <tr> <td align="left" valign="middle"><p style="font-size: 10px; font-style: normal; font-family: arial,verdana,sans-serif;  font-style: normal;"><a style="text-decoration: none; font-size: 10px; font-style: normal; font-family: arial,verdana,sans-serif;  font-style: normal;" title="Web hosting" href="http://ads.networksolutions.com/landing?code=P61C100S1N0B142A1D255E0000V100">Web Hosting</a> powered by Network Solutions®</p></td> </tr> </table> <!-- End content section --><!-- Start nsWebstats code.  Copyright 2010 networksolutions.com More info available at http://networksolutions.com --><script type="text/javascript">var pageName="login"; document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="'+(location.href.split(':')[0] =='https'?'https':'http')+'://stats.netsolads.com/jsconfig?pid=288656091%26mg=all%26lc=1%26pe=1"%3E%3C/script%3E'));</script><!--End nsWebStats tracking code. --></body></html>
```

Comment: If what you pasted is your PHP code, you have significant syntax issues. You'll want to start by simply getting the script to run without error.

Comment: What he said... start with `$password[0]` instead of `password(0)` and `$result_array[0]` instead of `$result_array(0)`.... and `$username[0]` instead of `username(0)`... etc.

Comment: Still get some [syntax errors](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ONSEkI), please debug it First. 
And a php code begin with `<?php` not `<php?`...

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but you could load the php file in a UIWebView which would then run the script, then when you want to retrieve variables back you could print them with php then use javascript to retrieve them and transfer the variables from javascript to objective-c using a method other's mentioned to me here: [iOS retrieving javascript variables from UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342609/ios-retrieving-javascript-variables-from-uiwebview/14342785#14342785)

Comment: I have been looking for a method to transfer variables from javascript to objective c. If I had a way that worked, I could avoid this entire mess. The app I am working on already has a server implemented which it communicates to using javascript. However I have tried several methods to transfer variables across the two languages, but every one of them fails. Hence I am trying to use php. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Did you see the link I posted? It shows you how to transfer variables from javascript to objective-c

Comment: Look up `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`

Comment: Yes I saw the link. I guess I could load it into a web view, and use that code. I do think it is simpler to run it natively though. 

when I said I have been looking for a method to transfer variables from javascript to objective-c, I mean that I am running a hybrid javascript/objective-c application and that I would need a objective-c javascript bridge. That is very difficult to implement, and so I am avoiding using any javascript that would make my application more complex.

http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/06/UIWebView-secrets-part3-How-to-properly-call-ObjectiveC-from-Javascript/

Answer (score 0):

If here is someone interested in an answer, thats a bit overkill for some trivial data-sendings i cound recommend to take a look on ActiveMQ. You could setup an server, and your iOS-Device can subscribe to queues on the server to recognize if other clients send data in the queues.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your php class with some wordpress plugin,or other php files that can interfere with your php file?

```
<script type="text/javascript">var pageName="token"; document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="'+(location.href.split(':')[0] =='https'?'https':'http')+'://stats.netsolads.com/jsconfig?pid=288656091%26mg=all%26lc=1%26pe=1"%3E%3C/script%3E'));</script><!--End nsWebStats tracking code. -->
```

Comment: My php code had a lot of errors in it. Once I fixed those, the program worked correctly. Thanks!